# I try to make linear layout translate using animation, left <-> right like this. but I got some error

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, translate

It's my first app, I try to make translate right to left or left to right.

Here is code

Res > anim > translate_left

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
Android: interpolator="@Android: anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
>
<translate 
    android:fromXDelta="100%p" 
    android:toXDelta="0%p" 
    android:duration="500"
    android:repeatCount="0"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Res > anim > translate_right

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    >

    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="0%p" 
        android:toXDelta="100%p" 
        android:duration="500"
        android:repeatCount="0"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

And

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MatchingActivity extends Activity {
boolean isPageOpen = false;

Animation translateLeftAnim;
Animation translateRightAnim;

LinearLayout slidingPage01;
Button openBtn01;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.matching);

    // Sliding Page
    slidingPage01 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.slidingPage01);

    translateLeftAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate_left);
    translateRightAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate_right);

    SlidingPageAnimationListener animListener = new SlidingPageAnimationListener();
    translateLeftAnim.setAnimationListener(animListener);
    translateRightAnim.setAnimationListener(animListener);


    // Open Button
    openBtn01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.openBtn01);
    openBtn01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // start animation
            if (isPageOpen) {
                slidingPage01.startAnimation(translateRightAnim);
            } else {
                slidingPage01.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                slidingPage01.startAnimation(translateLeftAnim);
            }

        }
    });

}

private class SlidingPageAnimationListener implements AnimationListener {

    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation){
        if (isPageOpen) {
            slidingPage01.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
            openBtn01.setText("Open");
            isPageOpen = false;
        } else {
            openBtn01.setText("Close");
            isPageOpen = true;
        }
    }

    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation){}

    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation){}

}

}
```

After launch this code some error comes out!

Error is

```
03-02 12:19:31.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1981): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 12:19:31.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1981): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start   activity   ComponentInfo{com.example.projectcupido/com.example.projectcupido.MatchingActivity}:   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: LinearLayout
03-02 12:19:31.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1981):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-02 12:19:31.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1981):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-02 12:19:31.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1981):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-02 12:19:31.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1981):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-02 12:19:31.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1981):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-02 12:19:31.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1981):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-02 12:19:31.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1981):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-02 12:19:31.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1981):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 12:19:31.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1981):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-02 12:19:31.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1981):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-02 12:19:31.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1981):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-02 12:19:31.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1981):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-02 12:19:31.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1981): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: LinearLayout
03-02 12:19:31.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1981):     at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:124)
03-02 12:19:31.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1981):     at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:91)
03-02 12:19:31.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1981):     at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:72)
03-02 12:19:31.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1981):     at com.example.projectcupido.MatchingActivity.onCreate(MatchingActivity.java:36)
03-02 12:19:31.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1981):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-02 12:19:31.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1981):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-02 12:19:31.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1981):     at        android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-02 12:19:31.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1981):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3):

I also got stuck in similar kind of situation in which i have to slide layout in all directions but i have done it below is my code may be it help you.

```
Animation Left slide
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" >
    </translate>

    Animation Right slide
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" >
    </translate>

    RightSwipe = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Screen.this, R.anim.right_swipe);
    ScreenAnimation.startAnimation(RightSwipe);
```

Comment: What is ScreenAnimation??

Comment: Your layout object

Comment: @ArpitPatel yes its name of my layout object, sorry for late reply

Comment: Thanks @Amit Gupta

Comment: @AmitGupta i have linearlayout with 3 weight sum. inside linearlayout I have one relative layout with weight 1.  so when I animate button from relative layout its move only with relative layout but I want to animate to main linearlayout do you know any solutions for that?