# How to add relative layout to relative layout with slide in effect?

Tags: java, android, layout, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout in which i add a second relative layout which contains 4 buttons. when i do:

`relativeLayout1.addView(relativeLayout2,params)`

i want that the added relative layout with the 4 buttons slides in from right to left.

[image: example]

Is that somehow possible?

xml:

`<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" >
    </translate>`

code:
```

```
public Panel(Context context) {
    super(context);

    this.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    this.setId(R.id.panel);

    right_menubar = new RelativeLayout(context);
    right_menubar.setId(R.id.panel_indicators);

    plp_right_menu_bar = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);

    this.addView(right_menubar, plp_right_menu_bar);

    Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.animator.anim);
    right_menubar.startAnimation(fadeIn);

}
```

Comment: You should take a look at [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696801/how-to-make-a-right-to-left-animation-in-a-layout

Comment: It is not working. Do i need call `relativeLayout2.startAnimation(animation)` after `relativeLayout1.addView(relativeLayout2, params)`?

Comment: Yes, you can make the view invisible before you add it, animate it to be off screen, make it visible and animate it to its final position.

Comment: Still not working, i have updated the code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now,

```
right_menubar.setId(R.id.panel_indicators);
plp_right_menu_bar = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
plp_right_menu_bar.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
this.addView(right_menubar, plp_right_menu_bar);
right_menubar.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getContext(), R.animator.anim));
```

No need to set it to invisible before the animation.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `100%` and `0%` use `100%p` and `0%p`

%p signifies percentage of its parent. i think that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: The animation is still not working. Any animation is not working

Comment: is the relative layout visibility set as visible before animating

Comment: i did not set visibility, but it is visible after i add the view. Before i have tried to set it's visibility to View.GONE and to View.INVISIBLE, but nothing changes