# Android Slide Trantition animation not working when using target

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, kotlin, transition

i want to crate animation from right to left when change activity, but not of window only certain layout, this is my code :

```
    val transition = Slide()
    transition.duration = 300
    transition.slideEdge = Gravity.END
    transition.mode = Visibility.MODE_IN
    transition.interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator(2f)
    transition.addTarget(R.id.ln_verification_phone)
    window.enterTransition = transition
```

but when i remove `transition.addTarget(R.id.ln_verification_phone)`, animation working but all of window, i want to target of view, are there wrong in my code, i try using `exclude` also not work

Comment: What I understood from your question is that you would like to animate a view inside an Activity and not an Activity itself. Is that right?

Comment: i want to create animation right to left in certain layout after onCreate activity using `Slide()`, i try like my code, not working, but i remove `addTarget` of view id what i want to animate, animation working but all window have animation right to left

Comment: yes like that @VijayE

Comment: Please look into this answer, it is well explained with code. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696801/how-to-make-a-right-to-left-animation-in-a-layout

Comment: thanks alot, you are the best @VijayE

Comment: but if using like that, not smooth in certain device

Comment: You are welcome @Bekti. If you can be specific what view you want to animate that would help me to find appropriate solution for you.